# Example of a strange metric space

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for a metric space  $(X,d)$ and two open balls $B_{\epsilon}(x), B_{\delta}(y)$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subset B_{\delta}(y)$ even though $\epsilon> \delta>0.$

I am thinking about the discrete metric but still not get it.

Comment: Well, if you use the discrete metric space and $\epsilon > \delta \ge 1$ then $B_\epsilon(x) =B_\epsilon (y) = X$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider you space is $[0, 2]$ with the Euclidean metric.  Let $x=2$ and $\epsilon = 1.5$.  Let $y=1$ and $\delta = 1.25$.

Then $B_\epsilon (x) = (0.5, 2]$ and $B_\delta(y) = [0,2]$.

Answer (score 1):

Take the metric space consisting of the three points $1,2,3\in\Bbb N$ with the standard metric. Take a ball of radius $1.5$ around $1$ and of radius $1.1$ around $2$.

Comment: Is it stil ok if the radius around 1 is 1.5 since the negative number is not included with our space $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Ahmed My space isn't $\Bbb N$. It's just those three points. But sure, assuming $0\notin \Bbb N$, the whole of $\Bbb N$ would work as well.